# Create an EKEvent with a few discrete days

Tags: ios6, eventkit

This sounds silly but I could not find an answer. I wanted to create an EKEvent with a few days (such as 9 to 10 am on 10/01/2013, 10/13/2013, 10/20/2013). How do I do that? I would hope that I could create only one event for these dates.

I thought I should use EKRecurrenceRule, but after reading and coding for while, i still do not get a good way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears not. Hope iOS7 could do.